# Javascript - message with local parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, date

I want to know the value of local parameter.

```
DateTime dFrom  = DateTime.Parse("15.12.2015");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert(dFrom);", true);
```

I got

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: dFrom is not defined"

can you help?
thanks

Comment: thanks you! working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `dFrom` is not declared in your JS code, you may change your code to this:

```
"alert(" + dFrom.ToString() + ");"
```

To convert it as a string which will be displayable.